# Very Slow Initial Break on Debug Point in WPF (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: wpf, performance, visual-studio-2010, debugging

The problem I seem to be having is that when I debug the WPF App the very 1st time it hits a break point, Visual Studio freezes for about 10 sec - after that behaves as normal. This is really becoming a pain, any way to address this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same problem, and it appeared suddenly, I noticed it freeze just if i press F10, or other key, if I press the green arrow button it go fast as usual, is it for you too?

Comment: Not quite the same, for me it just freezes once the 1st break point is hit, the IDE becomes unresponsive for ~10 sec, after that its back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable loading symbols: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols.